# Convolution of two sums (Fourier transform)

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

This question is from the book "Advanced Engineering Mathematics" by Stroud.

[image: Question]

I can't seem to get the required answer for this. I've derived the two Fourier transform equations for them.

[image: Transform]
.

U and V are dummy variables.

I've been told I need to use the convolution theorem by multiplying the functions in the frequency domain and finding the inverse transform of the solution, but I don't know how to proceed with the equations I've got.

Comment: Your equations for the Fourier transform are wrong. I don't know if it will help you answer the problem, but $\int {f(t)e^{-j\omega t} \mathrm{d}t}$.

Comment: You should consider that you are dealing with Fourier series, so $$c_k=\frac1{T}f_1(t)e^{-jω_0kt}\,dt.$$ And you should also look up your definition of the convolution product for periodic functions, it most likely is $$(f_1*f_2)(t)=\int_0^Tf_1(s)f_2(t-s)\,ds.$$

Comment: But is it possible to apply the convolution equation to sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform is a linear operator, so

$$
F_1(\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \mathcal{F}(e^{jn\omega_0 t}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \delta( \omega-n\omega_0)
$$

Use the above to multiply the two Fourier transforms. Then see if you can take the take the inverse transform to finish the proof.

**EDIT**:

To see how to find the product of the two sums note that

$$
\delta( \omega - n \omega_0) \cdot \delta( \omega - m \omega_0) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow n = m.
$$

Furthermore,

$$
m=n \Rightarrow \delta( \omega - n \omega_0) \cdot \delta( \omega - m \omega_0) = \delta( \omega - n \omega_0) = \delta( \omega - m \omega_0).
$$

Thus,

$$
d_m \delta( \omega - m\omega_0) \cdot \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \delta( \omega-n\omega_0) = d_m \delta( \omega - m\omega_0) \cdot c_m \delta( \omega - m\omega_0) = d_m c_m \delta( \omega - m\omega_0)
$$

**EDIT 2**:

We know that

$$
F_1(\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \delta( \omega-n\omega_0)
$$

$$
F_2(\omega) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} d_m \delta( \omega-m\omega_0)
$$

Their product is then

$$
F_1 (\omega) F_2 (\omega) = \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \delta( \omega-n\omega_0) \right) \left( \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} d_m \delta( \omega-m\omega_0) \right)
$$

By the definition of the Dirac delta function, we know that

$$
\delta(\omega - a) \cdot \delta( \omega - b) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
\delta(x-a), & a = b \\
0, & a \neq b
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Thus, if we consider an individual term in the series $F_1 (\omega)$ by fixing $n$ and take its product with $F_2(\omega)$, we get

$$
c_n \delta(\omega - n\omega_0) \left( \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} d_m \delta( \omega-m \omega_0) \right) = c_n d_n \delta(\omega - n\omega_0).
$$

Since this is true for all $n$, we have that

$$
F_1 (\omega) F_2 (\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n d_n \delta( \omega-n \omega_0).
$$

Comment: So there won't be any integration? Since the limits of the two sums are the same I can multiply them together? Like this: http://postimg.org/image/8qsyxsr1v/ ? (The second fuction is f2(omega).typo) My apologies if I'm making stupid mistakes here. This is all very new to me.

Comment: Absolutely not. In general, the product of two sums is not the sum of the element-wise products. Rather, it's what is called a [Cacuhy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). However, in this specific case, we are dealing with Dirac functions, which have the property that $\delta(x-a) \cdot \delta(x-b) = 0$ if $a \neq b$. You can use this property of Dirac functions to derive the product of these particular sums.

Comment: So do I have to obtain the Cauchy product in this situation? Wouldn't that property of Dirac functions make the entire equation 0?

Comment: Been working on this problem for two days now and still can't get it :S

Comment: @user2802349 See if my edit does not help.

Comment: I understand that part now :) Thanks so much. But I don't get why we don't have to use the Cauchy product in this case.

Comment: If you did use the Cauchy product and that's the reason dn became dm and n became m for the second part, how would we still know that n = m?

Comment: Because $n=m$ is the only time that $\delta( \omega - m\omega_0) \cdot \delta( \omega - n\omega_0)$ is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you so very much. So would this be correct? http://s12.postimg.org/l75bk6x6l/answer1.jpg. Could you also send me any good links on that property of Dirac Delta functions if you know of any? Would appreciate it.

Comment: @user2802349 You're getting there, but it's not quite right. You don't need the Cauchy product here (and your use of it is incorrect). I mentioned the Cauchy product only trying to be informative for the general case. I added another edit to my post. See if that helps clear things up.

Comment: Thanks so very much :) I'm sorry for having you spell it out for me :( If possible could you link me something with info for something that describes the δ(ω−mω0)⋅δ(ω−nω0) = 0 property? I'd like to learn more about the details of it so I can make my case!

Comment: @user2802349 You can check the wikipedia and mathworld pages, but it'd be easier to just analyze it. You know that $\delta(x)=1$ for $x=0$ and $\delta(x)=0$ for all $x\neq 0$. This is true by definition. So if you consider $\delta(x-a) \cdot \delta(x-b)$, what are the possibilities? If $x\neq a$, then $\delta(x-a)=0 \Rightarrow \delta(x-a)\cdot \delta(x-b)=0\cdot \delta(x-b)=0$ regardless of the value of $b$. The same situation exists when $x\neq b$. Thus, the only time the product is non-zero is when $x=a=b$, at which point it equals $1$. This is just the definition of $\delta(x-a)$.